# How to warm up a sleeping SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

We have a job which runs every morning in CruiseControl.net to import a datafile into a DB. Our problem seems to be that some nights the DB goes to sleep over night. When we run the script in the morning our connection times out while we wait for the DB to warm up. We've tried upping timeouts etc. but with no luck. Is there a way to tell SQL Server to warm up at a set time or to tickle it to keep it warm?

So far we run the job twice, once at 9am to warm it up which fails 80% of the time but at least it warms the server up and again an hour later which nearly always works.

I'd rather not run it twice as its a big job and very CPU intensive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Which version of SQL Server is this? It sounds like the database has the Auto Close setting on, which is the default for EXPRESS but can lead to behaviour like this.

Comment: I was indeed using SQLExpress, found the setting but right clicking on the DB -> Properties -> Options and set it to false. Thanks, fingers cross this fixes it :)

Comment: +1 thanks. Out of interest, why would this setting be turned on by default? It doesn't seem to be of any benefit to anyone.

Answer (score 14):

```
ALTER DATABASE myDB SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
go
```

Comment: +1 for the SQL command. It's going directly in my next update script.

Answer (score 1):

Could you schedule a query 30 minutes before your build process runs to "warm up" the server?

Also- is this database running on a server or desktop?  If it's a desktop you might check the power management settings.